# How to prevent Bootstrap carousel from resuming of the slide animation after clicking on right/left controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap Carousel to show show some images.
I already removed the `slide` class and the `data-ride="carousel"` from the carousel div in order to remove the automatic sliding animation.

But when you click in one of the right/left controls to change the image, **the slide animation resumes**.

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried adding a jQuery line above

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel("pause");
```

But this doesn't seem to help anyhow.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using this javascript line instead of the one you wrote at the end of your answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: 500, pause: "hover"});}
```

You can adjust the interval to whatever you want and this will pause whenever the carousel is hovered over by the mouse even after using the left/right controls, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this script:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $(this).carousel('pause');
})
```

- The `slid.bs.carousel` event "is fired when the carousel [has completed its slide transition](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events)".
- The `.carousel('pause')` method "[stops the carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-pause) from cycling through items".

Please check the result:

```js
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $(this).carousel('pause');
})
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```